# Crashes during UnhookWindowsHookEx()

Tags: c++, winapi

I made hook for calculator and want to get messages which calculator receives. To do that, I set my own window procedure, but during unhooking if I use `SetWindowLong(..)` to recover the old window procedure program crushes.

**DLL code:**

```
#define EXPORT_API extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXPORT_API void InstallHook();
EXPORT_API void UninstallHook();

#pragma data_seg("Shared")
HHOOK   g_hHook  = NULL;
WNDPROC g_OldWndProc = NULL;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:Shared,rws")

HWND GetTargetWindowHwnd()
{
return ::FindWindowA(0, "Calculator");
}

// my new wnd procedure to catch messages
LRESULT CALLBACK NewWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT lResult = 0;
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            MessageBoxA(0, "Here we are!", "", 0);
        }
        break;  
    default:
        lResult = CallWindowProc(g_OldWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    lResult = CallWindowProc(g_OldWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    return lResult;
}
// hook procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MSG *pMsg = (MSG *)lParam;
    HWND hWnd = GetTargetWindowHwnd();  
    bool flagIn = false;    

    if( hWnd == pMsg->hwnd )
    {// if messege was sent to my target window
        if(g_OldWndProc == NULL)
        {
            // save the adress of old wnd procedure to recover it later
            g_OldWndProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC);
            // set my wnd procedure
            SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)NewWndProc);
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

EXPORT_API void InstallHook()
{
    try
    {       
        g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC)GetMsgProc, g_hInstance, 0); 
    } 
    catch(...) 
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Hook error", "Error", 0);
    }
}

EXPORT_API void UninstallHook()
{
    if(g_OldWndProc)
    {
        // recovering old wnd proc
        HWND hWnd = GetTargetWindowHwnd();
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)g_OldWndProc);
        g_OldWndProc = NULL;
    }
    if (g_hHook)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hHook);
        g_hHook = NULL;
    }   
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInstance  = (HINSTANCE) hModule;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**EXE CODE:**

```
void CHookTestDlg::OnBnClickedBtnInstall()
{   
    InstallHook();  
}

void CHookTestDlg::OnBnClickedBtnUninstall()
{
    UninstallHook();
}
```

**If I don't use my wnd procedure it works normal. If I use SetWindowLong(..) to recover the old window procedure program crushes during unhook. What is wrong?**

Comment: You're going through a fair deal of effort here. What is it that you're trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: I want to imitate last actions which made by user with window. I set my window procedure and then transmit to main application all message which were received by target window.Then save them to vector and to imitate last actions. vector contains several messages i sent them by ::SendMessage() but there are no reaction from calculator

Comment: OK.  
Regarding the crash, try to write to a log what value does g_OldWndProc hold in the hook procedure when you set your window **subclass**, and again when you're unsubclassing. Perhaps they're different.  
  
Secondly, what you're doing is inherently unstable so results are hard to predict. Imitating user actions requires more than mimicking windows messages using `SendMessage()`. Some actions comprise of a sequence of messages that you'd have to send in the same exact order. Then, messages related to mouse activity contain coordinates that change easily.

Comment: To add to it, you need to filter the messages and re-send only those that are relevant. So it's tricky, but if you really want to just for the hell of it, study more about keystroke and mouse events to understand how they work and what you can do to re-create them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the window proc on the target window from within the target process (calc), and in that case, it is succeeding. But when you call UninstallHook, that code runs in your own exe's process; and in that case, SetWindowLong will fail.

(Putting the hook values in shared memory won't help; SetWindowLong will still refuse to change the window proc across a process boundary - see MSDN for details.)

To get this to work, you would need to communicate to the hooked instance of the DLL and ask it to reset the wndproc from within that target process, and once that is done, then unhook the hook.

(atzz's advice on unhooking is also valid. Hooking windows that you don't own is generally best avoided.)

Answer (score 3):

When unsubclassing, always check that the window was not subclassed by someone else after you. I.e. before restoring WindowProc, you should read it again and compare against expected value (`NewWndProc`). If it is different, you **must not unload** the DLL, because another subclasser has a pointer to your DLL code stored, and this pointer will become dangling as soon as your DLL is unloaded.